# Why are UK universities "disproportionately successful at winning EU-awarded research grants"?

Tags: funding, united-kingdom, europe

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Brexit&oldid=739916614#Academic_funding):

> UK universities rely on the EU for around 16% of their total research funding, and are disproportionately successful at winning EU-awarded research grants.

Why are UK universities "disproportionately successful at winning EU-awarded research grants"?

Comment: By what measure are they "disproportionately successful" at winning grants?

Comment: The Wikipedia article doesn't say. I would guess looking at some ratio [number of grants|grant money]:[population size|number of universities|number of academics].

Comment: This question was also raised by a professor at my University, it seems that they have specific technicals departments which are responsible for the guiding in writing a very good research proposals. Moreover, the research grants might be offered based on continuity in research for the institutions.

Comment: People speak English in the UK. Most academics are proficient in English. Not having to learn the local language is obviously a factor when deciding between job offers. As a result, UK universities have a competitive advantage over e.g. French or German universities when hiring, and they are able to hire more people with the potential to get EU funding.

Comment: I wonder if "UK Universities" means UK universities or just (Oxford + Cambridge). In the latter case, well, that's easy.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but extremely complex, debatable, and open-ended; it doesn’t seem like a terribly good fit for the StackExchange format..

Comment: @PLL many well-received questions are complex, debatable, and open-ended on this Stack Exchange website.

Comment: @JouniSirén You actually don't have to learn the local language, at least in Germany. Instead, we try to do everything in English, which results in massive communication problems, impeding science. Most academics are not very proficient in English, i'm afraid.

Comment: @Karl It's possible to work in English almost anywhere in the world. The hard part is living in a country permanently without speaking the language.

Comment: @JouniSirén The latter is a matter of personal taste, and how much of a shut-in you are. At my university, i personally know a dozen people who work and live here for years, and can hardly discuss the weather. I'd hate to live that way, but? The real problem is work: A team of five in which only one or two people can really communicate fluently is extremely inefficient. Discussions take forever, they often end before getting to the actual problem, misunderstandings, etc.

Comment: And: It doesn't improve over time. You don't learn English from talking to people who are as bad in it as yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Universities in the UK (and universities in Northern Europe in general) are just [better on average](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/student/best-universities/best-universities-europe-2016), with better infrastructure, better English skills, the means to hire better people, attract better students and in the end to write better grants (that might or might not be written by professional grant-writers). These are [Framework programme grants](https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/) for which there is Europe-wide competition.

This isn't entirely fair, that's why universities/research projects in poorer European regions are funded by the EU using more localized grants, as part of the [European Structure funds](http://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/en/funding/erdf/). Usually these grants are not open to Europe-wide competition, and the UK can't win them all.

Another comment on how "disproportionally successful" could be counted. If they just counted #grants-with-UK-participants / #grants the UK would come out ahead because of its large population (the same for Germany). Almost all grants will have UK / German groups involved, as it's hard to get 10 research groups & companies together without taking one from the UK (or Germany).

Comment: Did you just seriously quote the "Times Higher Education" ranking as a measure of good universities?

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion? The THE ranking is one of the best-known rankings, but all of them will put the UK ones at the top. So this argument is not that relevant.

Comment: Let me clarify. Did you seriously quote a ranking of universities, any one of the few that float around, as a measure of good universities? And it doesn't faze you in any way that in the "top 10" of European universities, 8 are from the UK? It's just like that, UK universities are intrinsically better in every way than all other European universities, it's a fact of life? You didn't stop to question the information fed to you?

Comment: This argument is not relevant, as UK universities are at the top of every ranking. Of course there are all sorts of issues with these rankings, but those don't change the results: no matter what you measure, UK universities are at the top. The rankings (and I) are also not saying they're better in every way, just better overall on average. And this partially explains the success of the UK in getting these grants.

Comment: The argument is worth dissecting because it appears again and again: a ranking is produced; its validity is basically destroyed by nearly every competent expert studying it, for gross bias or methodology reasons; and yet the ranking is still invoked as demonstrating some intrinsic features of the ranked entities. The whole operation seems to work like what they cal a self-fulfilling prophecy...

Comment: What measure would you use to call one university better than the other? I'm almost certain that in most reasonable measurements the UK universities will come out on top.

Comment: Fields medalists? (To be explicit, since this seems necessary, I am **not** advocating to take the number of Fields medalists as a measure of anything.) But the question you might want to ask yourself is not "which measure to decide that one university system is better than another" but what does it mean for a university system to be "better" than another? For example, is a given country the right scale to measure these things or is each country actually hosting several university systems? And so on. Oops, suddenly things are looking more complicated, (not) sorry for that...

Comment: Of course it's more complicated, I'm just saying that whatever you're looking at, some universities will just be "better" than others, no matter what you measure. And there are sufficient reasons to believe that the UK universities are on average better than the average EU university. And after that you're just trolling, country scale is EXACTLY right, since we're looking at countries here.

Answer (score 5):

The [Royal Society](https://royalsociety.org/~/media/policy/projects/eu-uk-funding/uk-membership-of-eu.pdf) has looked into this. The "disproportionately successful" claim is complicated. The [report says](https://royalsociety.org/~/media/policy/projects/eu-uk-funding/uk-membership-of-eu.pdf)

> The UK is one of the largest recipients of research funding in the EU and, although national contributions to the EU budget are not itemised, analyses suggest that the UK receives a greater amount of EU research funding than it 
>   contributes.

According to the report, the UK contributions account for 10.5% of the total EU budget, but the UK then "only" receives 6% of the total budget. The report claims that approximately 7% (5.4 billion out of 77.7 billion) of the UK contribution to the EU went to research funding and that 19% (8.8 billion out of 47.5 billion) of the money the UK received from the EU was for research. The report goes on to say

> There are two major routes by which the EU directly funds research in the UK – Framework Programme funding and structural funds. The UK is very successful in attracting Framework Programme funding, particularly that allocated for excellence. The UK recieves relatively little structural funding, which is largely targeted at building capacity in the least economically developed regions of the EU.

Roughly half the EU research budget is for "excellence" (the other half is for "capacity building"). There is a large asymmetry in distribution of the "excellence" funding with Germany, France, and the UK capturing approximately half of the excellence funding and only a quarter of the capacity building funding.

I do not think it is surprising that countries with strong "economies" are better able to capture funding earmarked for "excellence". If the EU shifted funding from excellence to capacity building, then the UK share would likely decrease. This in turn would decrease the UK share of the total EU budget and possibly lead to an earlier vote by the UK to leave the EU.

Comment: "There is a large asymmetry in distribution of the "excellence" funding with Germany, France, and the UK capturing approximately half of the excellence funding." -- well, these three countries have a population of 82+67+65=214 million, out of a total of 510 million. You would expect them to get "approximately half" of the funding, even if their universities/researchers were no better than those in the rest of the Union. It is certainly not a "large asymmetry". (But I would suspect that their share is actually much larger than "approximately half".)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth see edit. Germany, France, and the UK only account for 25% of the Capacity Building research funding. The UK only outperforms its contribution on one type of research funding.

Comment: Yes. But I still think that the three getting roughly 1/2 of the excellence funds is statistically not a "large asymmetry", simply based on the population numbers.